# Cannot redeclare class Facebook with facebook-php-sdk-master

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have been test successful already with my project used `Codeigniter` with  `facebook-php-sdk-master` for user login to facebook. Than i am back up it may be 2 month ago and now i just run it back i got errors message as

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Facebook in ../application/libraries/facebook.php on line 24
```

that this line have code

```
class Facebook extends BaseFacebook
       {
           //any code
       }
```

I don't know it's make by any problem. By i search in Google i get result because i have duplicate class name. but after i check it. it's show really no the same name of class in his project and other one why before it's run well and now ? 
Anyone have idea with it? please share to me now .

thanks

Comment: did you download the latest php sdk? do you include the sdk several times?

Comment: i am not sure for it's latest version or not because it's 2-3 month ago.

Comment: You need to add the code that you are using to include the facebook-sdk in your code. Is it included as a library?

Comment: yes i call it as simple

Comment: Do you have a controller that is called 'Facebook'?

Comment: no, controller call view to show and my view `include` it continue

Answer (score 1):

Try `include_once` as your code instead of `include`